# Is there a way to access the "arguments" object inside of a closure?

Tags: javascript, node.js, function, closures

I have a closure, and I want to access the arguments *to* the closure from *inside* the closure. Is this possible?

```js
function outerFunction (param1, param2) {
  // Returns [param1, param2, [param1, param2]]
  return function innerFunction () { return [param1, param2, arguments] }
}

// [1, 2, [1, 2]]
console.log(outerFunction(1, 2)(3, 4));
```

Comment: you can create a variable scoped in the function - also what you have isnt valid js

Comment: @skara9 I have corrected the typo, thank you!

Comment: what is wrong with the code you have? was it just the typo?

Comment: @skara9 Oh, I meant to write that it returned [1, 2, [1, 2]]. Sorry about that, I really should have proofread this question a bit more...

Comment: @skara9 [1, 2, [3, 4]]

Comment: should be fixed then

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`arguments` is a special beast, and follows different rules in sloppy mode than in strict mode. It is array-like, but not a real array. But it is not necessary to use it. Just use [rest parameter syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/rest_parameters):

```js
function outerFunction (param1, param2) {
  return function innerFunction (...args) { 
    return [param1, param2, args];
  };
}

let result = outerFunction(1, 2)(3, 4);
console.log(result); // [1, 2, [3, 4]]
```

Comment: Thank you! I didn't know spread syntax could be applied to function arguments.

Comment: @wibbuffey yeah, technically this isn't spread syntax but the [rest parameter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/rest_parameters).

Comment: @wibbuffey Also if you wanted `[1,2,3,4]` you could spread the args,  `return [param1, param2, ...args]`.

Comment: @Keith Yeah, I knew you could use spread syntax for that. That wasn't what I wanted; the return value was purely an example.